# Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE with multiples Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I would like to know how to handle a `QUERY` + `IMPORTRANGE` functions in order to combine data from several (40) google sheets, the links of which are in a table.

I cannot put them all in a single formula like so, it would be too long to type...

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Link1,"A1:E500");IMPORTRANGE(Link2,"A1:E500");IMPORTRANGE(Link3,"A1:E500");...},"Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

I did not manage to do it with an `INDIRECT` function

If there is a simpler solution, I am also interested !

Thank you !

Comment: It is confidential data, but all the sheets are exactly the same format and I have a list of around 50 sheets that changes some times. Therefore I need to handle the `IMPORTRANGE` function dynamically

Comment: Make (and share) a sample spreadsheet, with the table with the sample links as you've described.  We need to see the structure of your main sheet and one data sheet, and what you would like the outcome to like like.  We do not want to see any confidential data.  Create test data if necessary.

Comment: OK, 2 examples : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qdVKmfjaOxbxuj9F7rBJshwfSbfgNVHtBJw9WD2uRcU/edit#gid=0, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12BWUjF8jp-isGAnt4rZ3Sw2l5q9D0I-i84p2ncy5zHI/edit#gid=0

Comment: I can't see how to build that form of formula dynamically, from a list of the sheet URLs.  I think you'll need to keep doing what you are doing now.  The other option is to stack all of the IMPORTRANGE formulas in one sheet, to collect the data in one stack, and then run the query against that "temporary" stack of data.

Answer (score 1):

I get that you want to read two different Sheets and dump them all in a third Sheet using a formula. If that is correct, you are very close to solving this goal. You need to slightly modify your formula to match this:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("{FIRST SPREADSHEET ID}","{SHEET RANGE}");IMPORTRANGE("{SECOND SPREADSHEET ID}","{SHEET RANGE}")},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 <> ''")
```

Before using that formula you need to approve the connection to both Sheets. To do it, you need to copy each `IMPORTRANGE` separately and accept the dialog box when running it. If you still have questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer by the problem is I have not two but around 40 different spreadsheets...

Comment: Hi there @candyuiop! I used two Sheets on my answer to match the question, but the steps described are the same for forty, eighty or two hundred spreadsheets. You just need to keep adding `IMPORTRANGE("{SPREADSHEET ID}","{SHEET RANGE}")` for each Sheet, and separate them using `;`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is the spreadsheets id may change, as the number of spreadsheets...

Comment: @candyuiop, if the number of spreadsheets change or they get new IDs, you can update the formula to match the changes. I understand that this could be an intensive labor, would you be interested in a solution that uses [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to solve this issue? If so, please answer back indicating what is the common denominator of the Sheets so I can develop an update solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to do it using google script, and it is way easier...