# Copy lines from all sheets into a different sheet based on mutiple conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy/import lines from all sheets into one different sheet based on multiple conditions.

In other words, i need to automatically copy/import, from all existing sheets on spreadsheet, the lines where column B is "fruit" and column C is "red".

I can import the lines from Sheet1 like this:

```
=FILTER(
IMPORTRANGE("1HXbrA_Ks8yuIit6UOBdZEdan3hSRGnnuGvrIueDCbXM";"Sheet1!A2:C") ; 
           (Sheet1!B2:B = "fruit");(Sheet1!C2:C = "red")
)
```

But i need to import the correponding lines from all the existing sheets.

Maybe using a script is the right way to achieve this, but i am not able to do it.

Here is a live spreadsheet for testing:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HXbrA_Ks8yuIit6UOBdZEdan3hSRGnnuGvrIueDCbXM/edit?usp=sharing

This test spreadsheet have only 2 sheets, but the real spreadsheet have several sheets, so please take that into consideration.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Show your current script with [mcve]

Comment: Sorry but i do not have a script. I tried with filter direct into cell, but was not able to import from multiple sheets.

Comment: I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize. And also, when I saw your shared Spreadsheet, I found that the script is included. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511157 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958491

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the rows which have `fruit` and `red` in the columns "B" and "C", respectively.
- You want to put the retrieved rows to the destination sheet.
- You want to achieve above using Google Apps Script.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve all sheets.
2. From each sheet, retrieve the rows which have `fruit` and `red` in the columns "B" and "C", respectively.

   - At this time, `destinationSheetName` sheet is excluded.
3. Put the retrieved rows to the destination sheet.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set `destinationSheetName`. And in this sample script, `destinationSheetName` and "MERGED RED FRUITS" sheet in your shared Spreadsheet are excluded for retrieving rows.

```
function myFunction() {
  const destinationSheetName = "MERGED RED FRUITS (DESIRED RESULT)";
  const excludeSheetNames = [destinationSheetName, "MERGED RED FRUITS"];
  
  // 1. Retrieve all sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  // 2. From each sheet, retrieve the rows which have `fruit` and `red` in the columns "B" and "C", respectively.
  const values = sheets.reduce((ar, s, i) => {
    if (!excludeSheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName())) {
      const [,...v] = s.getDataRange().getValues();
      const temp = v.filter(([,b,c]) => b == "fruit" && c == "red");
      if (temp.length > 0) ar = ar.concat(temp);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // 3. Put the retrieved rows to the destination sheet.
  const dest = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  dest.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the duplication of the values is not checked. Please be careful this.
- When I saw your current script in your shared Spreadsheet, it seems that `getValue()` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will be high. So I proposed above flow.

#### References:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Nice! That seems to work properly. Looks good on test spreadsheet. I will try on my real spreadsheet and give a feedback! Thank you again Tanaike.

Comment: It worked perfectly on my real and larger spreadsheet. I just had to make some adjustments to fit the real dimensions of my real sheets. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will do what I think you want:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HXbrA_Ks8yuIit6UOBdZEdan3hSRGnnuGvrIueDCbXM/edit'); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  let currentRow = 2;
  let rows = []
  while(sheet.getRange("B" + currentRow).getValue() != "") {
    if(sheet.getRange("B" + currentRow).getValue() == "fruit" && sheet.getRange("C" + currentRow).getValue() == "red") {
      rows.push(currentRow)
      console.log("Match " + currentRow);
    }
    currentRow++;
  }
  Logger.log(rows)
  let destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEST');
  let deststartRow=5;
  for(var row of rows) {
    sheet.getRange("A"+row +":C"+row).copyTo(destSheet.getRange("A"+deststartRow +":C"+deststartRow))
    deststartRow++;
  }
 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it is leaving 3 lines empty and than importing only the lines of Sheet1.